# php xmlreader get all child nodes

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I have a php script using xmlreader to read an xml file and then pass the data to my database which all works fine. I am struggling with the images though. I can only work out how to get the first image of each property. Here is a sample of the xml

```
 <properties>
    <Property>
    <propertyid>17229-122</propertyid>
    <lastUpdateDate>2017-08-02</lastUpdateDate>
    <category>Residential For Sale</category>
    <images>
      <image number="1">
         <image>domain.com/imagefile1212.jpg</image>
         <alttext/>
      </image>
      <image number="2">
         <image>domain.com/imagefile12dfs2.jpg</image>
         <alttext/>
      </image>
      <image number="3">
         <image>domain.com/imagefile1212.jpg</image>
         <alttext/>
      </image>
    </images>
```

My php looks like this

```
$theFeed = "locationofthexmlfile.xml";

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($theFeed);


while($reader->read()) {

    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'Property') {
        $propCount++;
        // Get children of property
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($reader->expand(), true));
        #### get the data


        $ref = $xml->propertyid; // this works fine
        $img1 = $xml->images->image->image; /// this gets the first image

         ?????? how to I get all the other images like $img2,$img3 etc  

        }
}
```

I guess my question is how to I get all child nodes of the images node ? but I just cant work it our. Or should I be targeting each image by looking for the atrribute number='1' etc .

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You iterate the property or use SimpleXMLElement::xpath(), just like you would if you loaded the XML directly into SimpleXML. *btw* The `new DOMDocument()` should be outside the loop and you can provide it as an argument to `$reader->expand()` - making the importNode() unecessary.

Comment: Thanks TWH I will have a look at that now

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use "children()" in order to get access to all nodes.

For example:

```
$Img = $xml->Images->children();
```

or

```
$Img = $xml->Images->children()->children();
```

(depends how deep your nested array is)

After that, you could easily Loop with "for each"
or assign the values to each variable by

```
$Img1 = $Img[0];
$Img2 = $Img[1];
$Img3 = $Img[2];
```

Is this what are you looking for? :)